# Write multiple rows to a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a small GUI which should write the values ​​into a CSV file. However, the header is always written instead of just the new entries.

this is how it looks in the csv:

```
Amount, Time
1000,12:13:40
Amount, Time
2000,12:14:30
```

What I want:

```
Amount, Time
1000,12:13:40
2000,12:14:30
```

```
def submit():
     import csv
     import datetime
     with open("Data_amount.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
         writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
         #Header 
         writer.writerow(["Amount", "Time"])
         #Input
         input_amount = entry_listbox.get()
         #Time
         now = datetime.datetime.now()
         now_str = now.time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
         writer.writerow([input_amount, now_str])

     timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
     input_amount2 = entry_listbox.get() 

     if input_amount2 != "":
         listbox_stuekzahlen.insert(tkinter.END, f'{timestamp:%H:%M:%S} - {input_amount2} Stk.')
         entry_listbox.delete(0,tkinter.END)
     else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning!", message="INPUT!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You unconditionally write the header again each time you call `submit`. Either:

1. Remove that header write, and have, somewhere outside `submit` (early in your program, run exactly once), the code that initializes (opens in `"w"` mode so the file is cleared) the file with just the header, so each `submit` doesn't add an extra copy, or
2. Leave the header write in, but make it conditional on the file being empty (so you only write it when the file is already empty, and otherwise assume the file already has the header), e.g.

   ```
         with open("Data_amount.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
             writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
             #Header 
             if not os.fstat(csvfile.fileno()).st_size:
                 writer.writerow(["Amount", "Time"])  # Write header only if input is empty
   ```

Comment: how would you pre-write the header so that it is associated with the function?

Comment: @red: You can't "associate it with the function" in any reasonable way; Python doesn't have direct support for C-like `static`s where initialization only happens on first call, and trying to force such an implementation is... unpleasant. The code example I gave is the simplest way to "associate it with the function" (at the expense of an extra system call to check the size on each call). The other approach would be to make `submit` a method on a class, where the `__init__` of the class creates the file and writes the header, and you call `obj.submit` from there on out to add more lines.